# Why "off" in "off to the sides"

Tags: idioms, prepositions

I found online the following:

> Pedestrians are pushed **off** to the sides.
>
> either in the middle or **off** to the sides.
>
> **Off** to the sides were open fields.
>
> ...flows **off** to the sides of the...
>
> ...swam **off** to the sides.
>
> Even people **off** to the sides of these stage speakers enjoy
>   well-balanced, detailed sound...
>
> ...protesters would stand **off** to the sides yelling or booing...

Why not *at the sides* or simply *to the sides*? I understand *swam off to the sides* to mean *swam away to the sides*, but many others elude me.

---

Back to: "Pedestrians were pushed off to the sides". Interestingly, "push off" is also an idiom/phrasal verb with a totally different meaning. I imagine one can guess in our discussed case "pushed" and "off" are separate. That's one of the hardest things for non-native speakers of English, however, figuring out when those particles are part of the preceding verb, and when they are part of something else in a sencence. It adds to confusion. That's why you hardly ever hear non-natives using phrasal verbs and particles where the meaning is not very very very obvious. In addition I have not heard of a single book on the Enlish language explaining particles beyond the basics. Just saying.

Comment: Something is "off to" the side beacuse it is *away from* the focus of what is being discussed/going on.

Answer (score 4):

Compare:

> Even people **off** to the sides of these stage speakers enjoy
>   well-balanced, detailed sound...

to:

> Even people to the sides of these stage speakers enjoy
>   well-balanced, detailed sound...

In this case, there's the chance of misinterpretation if *off* is left out. It could sound like the people are directly at the sides of the stage speakers. *Off to the sides*, however, clarifies that there is distance at play and makes the sentence make more sense.

In other cases where it sounds unnecessary, it may be kept for sonorous purposes. In other words, we say it because it gives the feeling of the language flowing or maintains the rhythm of the sentence.

As another example, compare:

> The attack came not from the monster before her, but from those off to
>   the sides.

and

> The attack came not from the monster before her, but from those to the
>   sides.

In the first example, it's implying a long-range attack; are they shooting her with an arrow?

In the second example, it once again doesn't sound as far away. Maybe they're directly to either side of her or either side of the monster in front of her. In this case, it could conceivably be a close-range attack.

Comment: Thank you, I'm getting a much clearer picture now. How about this example:    

"The attack came not from the monster before her, but from those off to the sides." Before the attack, were the monsters some distance from her sides? If so, what distance?  

"The attack came not from the monster before her, but from those to the sides." Before the attack, were the monsters next to her sides (right beside her)?  

"The attack came not from the monster before her, but from those off at the sides." Is this one correct?

Comment: Sorry for no formatting. It does not work whatever I do.

Comment: Or another example: *"Pedestrians were pushed to the sides"* means the people were still on the road, but towards the sides. *"Pedestrians were pushed off to the sides"* means the people were no longer on the road, but on the sidewalks.

Comment: I've edited my answer to give additional detail based on your question @Neon.

Comment: "The attack came not from the monster before her, but from those off to the sides." This comes from a popular novel. There was no long-range attack. The monsters were really close and then clawed at the hero between them.

Comment: Then I fall back to my comment about it being used because it sounds better in cases where it doesn't change the meaning. I imagine in that case that the preceding sentences or the ones after  would have provided context as to the distance of the attack.

Comment: Although not precisely, the preceding sentences in the novel where, "The attack came not from the monster before her, but from those off to the sides."  provided the context, indeed.

Comment: In the case of the attacking monsters it's not the same "but from those off to the sides" than "but from those to the sides". *Off to the sides* gives the idea of a greater extension. The actual difference (if any) will depend on the greater context. If the greater context indicates that there is physical space to make a difference between "to the sides" and "off to the sides" well, the use of *off* will try to point that difference out.

Answer (score 2):

**"off":**

**1 down or away from a place or at a distance in space or time**

*I fell off the ladder.
Keep off the grass!
an island off the coast of Spain
They were still 100 metres off the summit.
Scientists are still a long way off finding a cure.
We're getting right off the subject.*

**2 leading away from something, for example a road or room**

*We live off Main Street.
There's a bathroom off the main bedroom.*

**3 used to say that something has been removed**

*You need to take the top off the bottle first!
I want about an inch off the back of my hair.*

Edit upon comment:

"at" is certainly static. It also implies higher precision of where somebody is standing. In the examples you write, the focus isn't on the people's exact position but on the fact that they are standing away from where the action is taking place.

I suspect that what bothers you is the use of the preposition "to" which is usually connected to movement. Since there is no further context, it might be possible that the people in your sentences are not totally immobile but are standing *off at the sides* readjusting their position (or forced to do so) to make sure that they will be away from the main focus.

Comment: Thank you. Still I don't see the explanation for the most difficult ones:

Even people off to the sides of these stage speakers enjoy well-balanced, detailed sound...
...protesters would stand off to the sides yelling or booing...

Why "off" here? Nobody is moving anywhere in these examples. They already stand there. Why not "at the sides of speakers?"

Comment: So if "people are off to the sides of stage speakers" what is the distance between them and the speakers? Are the people necessarily moving? And what are they off/away from?

Answer (score 1):

It's an unnecessary word and doesn't imply movement, but it is used to emphasize the distance just slightly.  "Pedestrians pushed to the sides" makes sense.  But "Pedestrians pushed off to the sides" means they are just farther away or that the speaker wants to emphasize that more.